# Flutter Android force open link in browser ignore deeplink

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, applinks

We have an SBP payment service that listens to many banking applications.

Example of a link: [https://qr.nspk.ru/AD10002V20O0JLDS83JAP5SO8NPB0D8P](https://qr.nspk.ru/AD10002V20O0JLDS83JAP5SO8NPB0D8P?type=02&bank=100000000008&sum=1000&cur=RUB&crc=F70B)

```
launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault);
```

How do I tell the Android operating system to open the link in the system browser without being intercepted via deeplink by third-party applications?

Answer (score 0):

It will be not possible to filter browser only. It will show all apps which support your specific deeplink url. You can either open url in the in App Web View or in App Browser View using LaunchMode.

```
launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView);
```

or

```
launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.inAppBrowserView);
```

Comment: The operating system does not show a window for selecting available applications. This behavior does not work in every android version. For example MIUI 13.0.2 Global Version it working, but MIUI 13.0.4 is not.